# Playfair Cipher tutorial C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, encryption

Is there any good tutorials on how to do a playfair encryption and decryption in C++?

regards,
newbie

Comment: I would say that it should be simple enough to take a look at an example of the cipher works (e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playfair_cipher)), and then write some C++ code to do it for you.

Comment: Hi Oli, thanks for the tips. I am new to c++ programming to be honest, I have come across lots of things like, array, list, and some others containers, I am not sure which one should I use. I have read the example from wikipedia, its all about 5x5 matrixes, so my guess, the simple one is to use array for newbie like me. I dont know where to proceed from here onwards. Perhaps, you have more tips for me?

Comment: @cppNewbie: If you are new to c++ then try to do it more than one way. Try it with arrays, try it with various containers like `vector`.

Comment: The Wikipedia article includes a link to http://www.umich.edu/~umich/fm-34-40-2/ which is an Army field manual for basic cryptanalysis. An example Playfair is decrypted in chapter 7 starting on page 12. You have given yourself a challenge.

Comment: Original Playfair uses a 5x5 grid so it has to omit a letter.  It might be simpler initially to use a 6x6 grid for 26 letters and 10 digits.  That way you will have to do less text manipulation before starting to encrypt.

Answer (score 4):

This is one of the rare questions where we can reasonably say no, there's no such thing.

Playfair encryption is not cryptographically safe. You would be able to find tutorials for modern, complex algorithms which are safe. However, you're learning C++, so a simple algorithm is indeed a better exercise.

Now, how should you approach such a problem then? The first thing to do is perform the task manually. If you can't do it yourself, there's no point in trying to "explain" the algorithm to a computer.

The second task is to identify the parts of a C++ program in the algorithm. Clearly, the "square" in the algorithm is a core data structure, and there are many functions that you perfrom with it. The conclusion is that the square should be the main class for your application. The square is initialized with a codeword, so the class constructor should take a string. Make a list of other well-defined tasks; those become methods of the class. E.g. the insertion of X to separate duplicate characters is one clear task. (And you need a special case to separate XX). If you're using the 5x5 algorithm, removing the 26th letter is another function.